# Tricky alignment within an equation with a case environment

Tags: horizontal-alignment, equations, align

I couldn't figure out how to do the following alignment:

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\textrm{Row I:} \qquad & A = 1, \quad j = 1, 2, \ldots, N \\
\textrm{Row II:} \qquad & A = 
\begin{cases}
2, & j = 1, 2, \ldots, m, \\
3, & j = m+1, \ldots, N
\end{cases} \\
\textrm{Row III:} \qquad & A = 4, \quad j = 1, 2, \ldots, N
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
```

which gives

[image: equation image]

However, I want the equal signs for the 'j's aligned. Any ideas how this might be done? I know it could be done in a tabular environment using a multi-row environment, but the equation spacing would be all off.

Answer (score 5):

Identify the widest entry and add the spacings manually; in the rows without `cases` add `\hs` and `\hp`, while only `\hs` is needed for the entries in `cases`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,calc}
\newcommand{\setwidest}[1]{%
  \renewcommand\widest{\mathmakebox[\widthof{#1}][l]}%
}
\newcommand{\widest}{}
\newcommand{\hp}{\hphantom{\Bigg\lbrace}}
\newcommand{\hs}{\hspace{2\arraycolsep}}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\setwidest{222,}
\begin{aligned}
\textrm{Row I:}  \qquad & A = \widest{1,} \hs\hp  j = 1, 2, \dots, N \\
\textrm{Row II:} \qquad & A = 
\begin{cases}
\widest{222,} \hs j = 1, 2, \ldots, m, \\
\widest{3,} \hs j = m+1, \ldots, N
\end{cases} \\
\textrm{Row III:} \qquad & A = \widest{4,} \hs\hp j = 1, 2, \ldots, N
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\setwidest{1111111,}
\begin{aligned}
\textrm{Row I:}  \qquad & A = \widest{1111111,} \hs\hp  j = 1, 2, \dots, N \\
\textrm{Row II:} \qquad & A = 
\begin{cases}
\widest{222,}\hs j = 1, 2, \ldots, m, \\
\widest{3,}\hs j = m+1, \ldots, N
\end{cases} \\
\textrm{Row III:} \qquad & A = \widest{4,} \hs\hp j = 1, 2, \ldots, N
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ah. I think this works for this example, but as soon as the size of the columns change, multiple phantoms might be necessary (e.g. change the "2" case to "222222222")

Comment: @TSGM I changed the implementation. Some manual work is needed, though.

Answer (score 5):

A solution using `alignedat` instead of `aligned` and `aligned` instead of `cases`. The *alignment* is also *automatic* regardless the width of the boxes and without `\hphantom`s.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\begin{alignedat}{3}
\textrm{Row I:} \qquad & A = 1,& \quad &j = 1, 2, \ldots, N \\
\textrm{Row II:} \qquad & A = \Bigg\lbrace
\begin{aligned}
2,\\
3333,  
\end{aligned} &
&\!\begin{aligned}
 j &= 1, 2, \ldots, m, \\
 j &= m+1, \ldots, N
\end{aligned}\\
\textrm{Row III:} \qquad & A = 4,& \quad &j = 1, 2, \ldots, N
\end{alignedat}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

or

```
\begin{aligned}
&2,\\
&3333,  
\end{aligned} &
```

if you want to align at left

[image]

Answer (score 2):

A rudimentary implementation using an straight-forward `array`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\centering

-- Original --
\begin{equation}
  \begin{aligned}
    \textrm{Row I:} \qquad & A = 1, \quad j = 1, 2, \ldots, N \\
    \textrm{Row II:} \qquad & A = 
      \begin{cases}
        2, & j = 1, 2, \ldots, m, \\
        3, & j = m + 1, \ldots, N
      \end{cases} \\
    \textrm{Row III:} \qquad & A = 4, \quad j = 1, 2, \ldots, N
  \end{aligned}
\end{equation}

-- \verb|array| implementation --
\begin{equation}
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.4}
  \begin{array}{r@{\qquad}r@{}l@{\quad}r@{}l}
    \textrm{Row I:} & A & {}= 1, & j & {}= 1, 2, \ldots, N \\
    \textrm{Row II:} & A & {}= \Bigg\{
      \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}\begin{array}{@{}l@{}} 2, \\ 3, \end{array} & 
      \multicolumn{2}{@{}l@{}}{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}\begin{array}{@{}r@{}l}
        j & {}= 1, 2, \ldots, m, \\
        j & {}= m + 1, \ldots, N
      \end{array}} \\
    \textrm{Row III:} & A & = 4, & j & {}= 1, 2, \ldots, N
  \end{array}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```